Why the differences in timeline between Daniel 8:13, 14 and Daniel 12:11?
Is it true that the only difference here is Dan 12:11 referring to latter half after the Abomination of Desolation whereas Dan 8:13, 14 is the referring to from where the sacrifices begin all the way through to the end of the seven year period? Is this an indication that gives us the timeline from how long it takes to build the third temple.
2550 days (full seven years) minus 2300 days (Dan 8:14) equals 250 days (time it takes for third temple build from the start of the seven years)?

Welcome to Biblical Hermeneutics! I don't see a question for which you are seeking an answer. When you get a chance, please take the [tour] to understand how the site works and how it is different than others. I also recommend going through the Help Center's sections on both asking and answering questions.

I’m voting to close this question because this is a statement and not a question.

Sorry, is there a question here?

I have taken the liberty of asking a question but if I have misunderstood what it is you want to know, then please edit the top line (which must be a question) so you post will stay up.

Two Different PropheciesMany who try to interpret the prophecies of Daniel make the mistake of lumping them together. They think that if numbers are similar they must refer to the same time zone; or if an "abomination" is mentioned, it must be the same event (person); or if a "daily sacrifice" is referred to, it must be the same time.
However, the interpretations of the angels---and Jesus---must not be overlooked. Nor must they be ripped out of their historical context. Daniel was given several different prophecies at different years in his life, with different messages.
Daniel 8From the very first verses were are told that this is a vision about the rise of the Media-Persian empire with its overthrow by the Grecian empire, which was subsequently divided into four domains.
History has verified the vision of this "Ram and Goat" episode as the Persian armies being defeated by the Greeks, especially Alexander the Great's armies. And then Alexander's empire was divided amongst his four generals (with just two of them rising to prominence: the Seleucids and the Ptolemies.
It is within this history that the times of Daniel 8:13-14 are placed. And they must not be interpreted as being some time later.
Daniel 12The 12th chapter of Daniel (along with chapter 11) is a totally different perspective. It describes in more detail the intertestament period of Jewish history. It begins with the long struggle between the Seleucids (in the north of Israel), and the Ptolemies (south of Israel). And then it narrows down to the era of the Herodian kingships.
And then the prophecy focuses on Judea at the time of Christ, and the presentation of the Gospel to the people. It reiterates what was mentioned in chapter 9 about the coming Destruction of the Second Temple. Notice Jesus's reference to Daniel, linking this passage with the pending doom to befall Jerusalem in 40 years (70 A.D.)

There shall be a time of trouble, such as never was since there was a nation even to that same time. (12:1, compare Matthew 24:21)

Jesus enumerated the "signs" leading up to that horrible destruction---not just of the Temple, but of the whole region of Judea! Most Bible readers do not realize that the destruction by the Romans lasted 3 1/2 years, from 67-70 A.D., and went from "Dan to Beersheba, " not just the city of Jerusalem!
Time of DestructionIn fact Daniel was given the exact time frame that the Jews would have to endure at the hands of the Iron Machine of Rome. (see Luke 21:20-24). This is referred to in Luke as the times of the Gentiles (vs. 24).

From the time that the daily sacrifice shall be taken away, and the abomination that makes desolate set up, there shall be a thousand two hundred and ninety days. (vs. 11)


Blessed is he who comes to the thousand three hundred and thirty-five days. (vs. 12)

History has verified these dates! The conquest by the mean Roman machine lasted  for 1,290 days (67-70,approximately 3 1/2 years). The city of Jerusalem was eventually attacked, and the Temple was demolished, stone by stone just as Jesus predicted. But there was just one fortress (Herod's palace) that would not surrender, and it held out for another month and a half...exactly the length of time the angels said: 1335th day! And for no reason. It surrendered even though they had supplies for a lot longer period!
Dispensational TeachingsIn 1830, a young man named John Darby began teaching a new doctrine about a "third Jewish temple" with a lot of End Time signs, and a distinct Jewish dispensation. Mixing Daniel 9:27, Daniel 12, and N.T. references of a "man of sin", he came up with a montage of supposed End Time wars and intrigue.
While most traditional Protestant denominations did not believe any of this, this "new doctrine" of eschatology has spread into may local churches, influenced by the publication of the Scofield Bible, and the professors at Dallas Seminary.
But a knowledge of, and application of, Roman and Jewish history confirms the traditional approach to Daniel's prophecies, herein presented. These, and Jesus's teaching in Matthew 23-25, are a strong apologetic for the supernatural character of the Bible--and the truthfulness of the Christian religion.
ResourcesFor further information research, Oswald T. Allis, Prophecy and the Church; Philip Mauro, Matthew Twenty-four, and the Great Tribulation; Marcellus Kik, Matthew Twenty-four; Raymond Grant, Times, They Are A'changing.
NoticeIt is important to note---and this will help in correctly interpreting Daniel---there is to be no third temple. After the 2nd Jewish Temple was destroyed, the N.T. is abundantly clear that there is a New Covenant that encompasses all peoples around the world (John 3:16).  And all the things pertaining to the old temple in the Kingdom of Israel worship are now finding fulfilment in the Church which is the Kingdom of God (Hebrews 8:13, 1 Peter 2:5-9, q.v.) The sacrifices of praise, the priesthood, the intercession, the spiritual worship...all make a third temple unnecessary! We, the people of God are the Temple wherein the Holy Spirit dwells; a Temple not made by hands (Read the whole Book of Hebrews!).

@ Ray Grant. In reguard to Dan. 9:27, do you see that Jesus fulfilled this in his dying on the cross and as Hebrews depicts, fulfilled the eternal sacrifice? He also said in the last verses of MT.23 just before the Olivet prophecy that Israel's house was left desolate. So instead of the antichrist making the LAST of the 70th week covenant, Jesus fulfilled it with the New Covenant.

@ RHPclass79 - Absolutely! The main message of Daniel 9 is the coming of Christ to fulfill the six objectives listed here (9:24)...by being cut off in the middle of the 70th week (crucified), and "confirming the Covenant for the many", as Mark recorded (14:24).  There is no anti-Christ mentioned at all in Daniel 9., just Christ (Messiah the Prince) (9:25). ---Because of your enlightenment, "Thou art not far from the Kingdom! " (As Jesus would say.)

@ Ray Grant. God bless you! There is someone else who reads their Bible rather than just contemporary books. I haven't found many that see what we do though.

Dan 8:13, 14 contre Dan 12:11
The analysis of the passages of Daniel 8:13-14 and Daniel 12:11 requires a thorough exegetical and hermeneutical approach. These verses, although distinct, come together on several theological and historical points. We will examine their context, their content, their exegetical analysis, their hermeneutical interpretations, as well as their theological implications.

Context of the Verses**
Daniel 8:13-14
Context: This passage is part of a broader vision where Daniel observes a ram and a goat, symbolizing kingdoms in conflict. The angel asks Daniel how long the vision will last, which underlines the anguish in the face of the persecution of the saints.
Content :
-Verse 13: A saint asks about the duration of the vision concerning the abomination and desolation, highlighting the concern about the sufferings to come.
-Verse 14: The angel's answer specifies that the period of suffering will last for 2,300 evenings and mornings, after which the sanctuary will be purified. This purification is interpreted as a restoration after desecration.
Daniel 12:11
Context: This passage is part of a final revelation to Daniel, which addresses the events of the end times. The context is marked by revelations concerning the resurrection and the judgment.
Content:
-Verse 11: It is mentioned that from the moment the perpetual sacrifice is taken away and the abomination of desolation established, there will be 1,290 days. This verse highlights a period of tribulation related to the end times.
Exegetical Analysis
Common Themes
Both passages address themes of suffering and purification, but they differ in the duration of the trials:
-Daniel 8 speaks of 2,300 evenings and mornings, a period that can be interpreted as specific to the purification of the temple after the desecration by Antioch IV.
-Daniel 12 mentions 1,290 days, often associated with eschatological events.
Symbolism
-Evenings and Mornings: In Daniel 8, these terms can be interpreted as specific periods of time, representing a clear sequence of days.
-Days: In Daniel 12, days are often perceived as periods of judgment or purification, highlighting the urgency of upcoming events.
Hermeneutical Interpretations
Comparison of Durations
The differences in the durations between the two passages are significant :
-Daniel 8 is often seen as referring to the period of Greek domination, with a particular focus on the purification of the temple after desecration.
-Daniel 12 is usually associated with the events of the end times, indicating a period of tribulation, followed by deliverance.
Theological Implications
These verses are frequently used to discuss the themes of suffering, hope and divine restoration:
• The suffering of the saints is a central theme, illustrating the struggle between good and evil.
• The difference in the durations can be interpreted as a way of emphasizing the urgency of the upcoming events, calling believers to vigilance and preparation.
Conclusion
The study of Daniel 8:13-14 and Daniel 12:11 highlights tensions and complementarities in biblical prophecies. The differences in the durations reveal distinct historical and theological contexts, while sharing common themes of suffering and hope. A careful reading of these texts enriches our understanding of their meaning within the framework of the Christian faith.
Final Thoughts
The verses of Daniel remind us of the importance of perseverance in faith in the face of trials. They also encourage a reflection on the nature of time in the divine plan, where each period of suffering is followed by a promise of restoration. In a world often marked by uncertainty, these passages offer a perspective of hope and trust in divine providence.
Thus, the exegesis and hermeneutics of these texts invite us to deepen our relationship with God, through prayer and the study of the Scriptures, while remaining attentive to the signs of the times.

Sources and methodologies:
The exegetical and hermeneutical study of biblical texts, such as Daniel 8:13-14 and Daniel 12:11, is based on several sources and methodologies. Here are some of the main sources that can be used in this approach:

Biblical Texts
-Bible: The translations of the Scriptures (such as the Louis Segond, the Jerusalem Bible, or the New Segond Version) provide the basic text for analysis.
-Septuagint: The Greek translation of the Old Testament, which can offer different perspectives on the Hebrew texts.
Biblical Commentaries
-Specific Comments: Books such as John Walvoord's Commentary on Daniel or J. A. Montgomery's Commentary on the Book of Daniel provide detailed analyses of the verses.
-Modern Commentaries: Recent works, such as those of the New International Commentary on the Old Testament series, offer contemporary perspectives.
Works of Theology
-Old Testament Theology: Books such as The Theology of the Old Testament by Walter Brueggemann explore the theological themes present in the prophetic books.
-Apocalyptic Theology: Studies on the apocalypse, such as those of Richard Bauckham, examine the characteristics of apocalyptic writings.
Historical and Cultural Studies
-Historian: Research on the historical context of the time of Daniel, in particular the period of the Babylonian and Greek empires.
-Culture and Religion: Studies on the religious beliefs and practices of the time can help to understand the symbols and metaphors.
Textual Analysis Tools
-Linguistic Analysis: The use of Hebrew and Aramaic for a deeper understanding of words and phrases.
-Textual criticism: Evaluation of textual variants and ancient manuscripts to establish the most reliable text.
Academic Articles and Journals
-Theological Journals: Articles published in journals such as The Journal of Biblical Literature or Vetus Testamentum provide recent studies and debates on specific passages.
Online Resources
-Bible Databases: Resources like BibleGateway or Blue Letter Bible offer study tools and commentaries.
-Bible Encyclopedias: Books like The Anchor Bible Dictionary provide contextual and historical information.
Conclusion
These sources, combined with a rigorous methodological approach, make it possible to carry out an in-depth exegetical and hermeneutical study of the biblical passages, taking into account their historical, cultural and theological context.


Welcome again, Jeremie. Just to point out that the o.p., who is a new user, has not actually asked a question, and an answer without a question just floats around, unable to latch on to anything! It can only be a comment. Because this site requires a specific question, unless the o.p. edits one in, this will be closed down. This site is not for discussions, personal opinions, or a forum to post one's own views on. The o.p. needs to do the Tour, and check the Help links (below, r.h.s.) to learn what this site requires by way of questions (or answers).

Lesley has just turned the o.p's statement into a question, which might save it from being closed down.
